# Is there a RDS aurora synchronous read replica?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, database-replication, amazon-aurora

If I understand correctly, Amazon Aurora has asynchronous read replica. So, we can get some read lag (it seems, lag is about `100 ms`).

I need synchronous read replica. So, can I set such type of replicate for Amazon Aurora for PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry but you can't change Aurora Replication type, Aurora is Amazon Aurora has asynchronous read replica but the lag isn't a major problem normally it is just a few milliseconds, not all the time 100 ms.

For additional information please refer to https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/faqs/

Answer (score 1):

If you need a synchronous read replica I would recommend using a write-through cache architecture using ElastiCache "in front" of Aurora or similar to help scale out reads.